# Use Azure DocumentDB as database for Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, azure, django-rest-framework, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to find any way to use the Azure DocumentDb with the Django Rest Framework.  I know there isn't much information in this question, but thus far I have found nothing through searching on how to do this.  Can anyone point me to info or documentation on this?

From what I've read it seems like Django is mainly geared towards using relational databases, but I have seen some people use it with MongoDB.  Being new to Django, specifically what I believe I'm looking for is what to change here in the settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is actually off-topic: you're asking for off-site resources. Also, you're asking about what database types are good for django. Just look at various documentation to see what databases are supported.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I would have accepted an answer, I was just trying to say if there is information I'll gladly go read it to find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works out of the box with MongoDB, try using the MongoDB driver-level compatibility mode for DocumentDB. Since Django is designed with any database in mind, I suspect that it's not using the more esoteric aspects of MongoDB that are not supported by the MongoDB API for DocumentDB so I think there is a good chance it will work.

Comment: That may be my best option

Comment: Django doesn't directly support databases other than relational databases. There are forks which support MongoDB (and a few others) but this is not core Django.